# Table as parameter incorrect type

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I created function and new type to hold my table but now I get error

> Operand type clash: nchar is incompatible with TableArgId

I'm using the Northwind database.

My code below.

```
USE Northwind
CREATE TYPE TableArgId 
     AS TABLE
        ( ID NVARCHAR(16));

GO
CREATE or ALTER FUNCTION MyFunc
(
    @clientid TableArgId READONLY
)
    RETURNS @tablica TABLE(
        CustomerID NVARCHAR(16), 
        Category_ID INT, 
        Category_Name NVARCHAR(128)
    )
    AS
    BEGIN
        INSERt INTO @tablica
    SELECT 
        CustomerID, 
        B.CategoryID,
        C.CategoryName
    FROM
    @clientid AS TabID LEFT JOIN 
    Invoices AS A ON TabID.ID = CustomerID
    left join Products AS B ON A.ProductID=B.ProductID
    left join Categories AS C ON B.CategoryID=C.CategoryID;
    RETURN
    END
    GO


SELECT * FROM MyFunc((SELECT CustomerID FROM Invoices WHERE CustomerID = 'QUEEN'));
```

Can I set the type returned by the SELECT?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can I set the type returned by the SELECT?

No - you have to assign it to a variable first e.g.

```
DECLARE @Param TableArgId;

INSERT INTO @Param (ID)
  SELECT CustomerID
  FROM Invoices
  WHERE CustomerID = 'QUEEN';

SELECT *
FROM dbo.MyFunc(@Param);
```